# How to extract subset of a dataframe that has the largest maximum row value within a subset of a subset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (df) that contains datapoints along rivers, where each river basin (Basin ID) contains multiple rivers (River ID), and each river has points along its length (Length). It looks something like this (simplified):

| Basin_ID | River_ID | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |

In this example Basin 1 has three rivers, and Basin 2 has two rivers. The actual table has 600K rows and 12 other columns with other river data.

**Objective:** I want to extract the single longest river subset for each unique basin in df, so that I end up with something like this:

| Basin_ID | River_ID | Length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 1 | 14 |

I assume that I would need to do something like

```
res = df.groupby('Basin_ID').apply(lambda x: ...
```

But because I need to group both by Basin_ID and River_ID, I am finding it hard to come up with an expression that works as it should.
Any advice welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2=df.assign(maxRiverLength=df.groupby('Basin_ID').transform(lambda x: x.max())['Length']).set_index(['Basin_ID','River_ID'])
df.set_index(['Basin_ID','River_ID']).loc[df2[df2['Length']==df2['maxRiverLength']].index].reset_index()
```

There might be a smarter way, but I reproduced your output in 2 steps:

- I first create a new column containing the maxRiverLength per Basin_ID and assign this to a df2 where I set the index to Basin_ID and River_ID:
- I then take the original df, set the index to Basin_ID and River_ID as well
  and filter by the indexes of df2 having 'Length' = 'maxRiverLength'

Comment: Hi Daniel! At first this wasn't working, but that's because I didn't realize I had to set the second line as an output. I changed it to something like
df_final = df.set_index(['Basin_ID','River_ID'].... etc., and now that df_final is beautifully simplified! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! yes, I guess that's a bad habit of mine to reuse variables..ill keep that n mind